# div fixa no rodapé do navegador

Tags: html, css

Eu estou precisando deixar uma div que seria um botão de "Comprar" fixa no rodapé do navegador. Deixar ela no final do monitor, e mesmo que o scroll role para baixo, continua na mesma posição, no final. Como poderia fazer usando HTML / CSS ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tenta:

```
position:fixed;
bottom:0px;
```